# i want to fetch the authenticated user orders detail with Api i am developing api for mobile eveloper

Tags: laravel, api

```
i am using api:auth route  and getting empty array on postman please help me to solve this i wanted to get order history of loged in user
```

My Relationships look like this

In User model-

```
product()
purchases()
```

In Product model-

```
purchases()
user()
```

In Apple model

```
product()
user()
```

My Apples.php table look like this

```
$table->string('transaction_id');
$table->string('buyer_name');
$table->integer('user_id');

$table->string('address');
$table->string('phone');
$table->string('email');
$table->string('city');
$table->string('payment_method')->default('Apple Pay');
$table->string('plan_id');
$table->text('selected_products_ids');
$table->string('plan_purchase_date');
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->timestamps();
```

my Contrller is

```
$order= Apples::where('user_id', auth('api')->user()->id)->with('product.purchases');
```

Comment: its throws empty array in postman

Comment: and yeah, you're missing the `get()` on your query

Answer (score 1):

Just add the relation HasMany `apples()` in the User model and fetch it like this

```
$order = auth('api')->user()->apples()->with('product.purchases')->get();
```

Comment: i add this to mu user model still get empty result in Postman  
public function apples()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Apples');    
}

Comment: @AbdulAmeer have you checked that you have `Apples` linked to the `auth('api')->user()` you're using ?

Comment: @AbdulAmeer if your issue is cleared, dont forget to choose an answer